# limits.conf not being read when logging in

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ulimit

I have 2 entries in my limits.conf,

```
*       hard        nofile      10240
*       soft        nofile      4096
```

but running `ulimit -Sn` or `ulimit -Hn` only displays the default values.

```
gabriel@server:~$ ulimit -Sn
1024
gabriel@server:~$ ulimit -Hn
4096
```

It works fine on one server but on another it's as if they're being ignored.
I did have a problem with `apt-get autoremove` for some old kernels on this one server which I didn't have on the other, I didn't note it down but I'm quite able to reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was down to the custom ssh configuration we had, it was not using the pam modules so the limits were not getting set.